# Using redis keyspace notifications to know which member was added to or removed from a set

Tags: redis, event-notification

My use case is that whenever a member is added to or removed from a set, a keyspace notification should be triggered that has information about what member was added or removed and put that pub/sub event into a redis stream for reliable communication. I am doing this using redis gears. Here's the python code used in redisgears:

```python
GearsBuilder()
.foreach(
    lambda x: execute(
        "XADD",
        "mystream",
        "*", 
        *x.items()
        )
    )
    .register(
        prefix="*",
        eventTypes=["SADD","SREM"],
        mode="sync"
    )
```

Currently, it only emits an event that tells that SADD or SREM was used on my set which is not very useful.

Note that `prefix="*"` is only for debugging purposes and I'll correct it later to only listen for changes to a specific set.

I have registered a keyspace notification listener using the `KEA` flag which is again, just for debugging purposes.